# RazorpayCheckout is undefined in ionic payment integration

Tags: ionic-framework, payment-gateway, razorpay

I tried to integrate razorpay with my ionic3 App , I got code from github 
it successfully debit payment from account but it doesn't return payment id to my app

I followed steps from here : https://medium.com/enappd/how-to-integrate-razorpay-in-ionic-4-apps-and-pwa-55415fd9c1a9

```
  var options = {
  description: 'Credits towards consultation',
  // image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
  currency: 'INR',
  key: 'xxxxxx',
  amount: this.amount * 100,
  name: this.name,
  prefill: {
    email: this.email,
    contact: this.mobileNumber,
    name: this.name
  },
  theme: {
    color: '#F37254'
  },
  modal: {
    ondismiss: function() {
      console.log('dismissed')
    }
  }
 };

 var successCallback = function(payment_id) {
  alert('payment_id: ' + payment_id);
  callApi(payment_id, options.amount);
 };

 var cancelCallback = function(error) {
  console.log('fail');
  console.log(error.description + ' (Error ' + error.code + ')');
 };

 Razorpay.open(options, successCallback, cancelCallback);
```

Actually i saw this type of question from stack but no answer that question,

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002415/how-to-redirect-to-page-after-success-from-razorpay-in-ionic-3)   from this code, I changed
    "Razorpay.open to RazorpayCheckout.open " ,    but it shows this error  "razorpaycheckout is not defined cordova"

Give me some suggestions to fix my issue

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Install inapp browser and change RazorpayCheckout to open

Comment: @MeenaArumugam are u fix above issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code in your declarations `.d.ts` file

1. declare module `'*';`
2. declare var RazorpayCheckout: any;

Please check below link for your [reference](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova-sample-app/blob/master/rzp-ionic2-example/src/declarations.d.ts)